# nifi Could not find Process Group with ID

Tags: apache-nifi

After installing nifi, I am trying to create a flow to test hdfs-nifi connectivity. But I am getting following error continuously for every click on the dashboard.

I am the root. so I have complete access to the components.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Did you copy a `flow.xml.gz` file from an existing instance of NiFi, or have controller services, reporting tasks, or other components which reference a group that no longer exists?

Try searching for the UUID using the search bar in the top right, or shut down NiFi, and use the following terminal commands to look for any references to this process group ID (double check or copy/paste the UUID because I typed it from looking at your screenshot):

```
cd $NIFI_HOME
gunzip -k conf/flow.xml.gz
grep '1861df7a-0168-1000-3931-028d9eb92cbd' conf/flow.xml
```

You should remove the referenced process group (you can back up the `flow.xml.gz` first if you are concerned about data loss (this would be the flow definition, not any flowfiles, content, or provenance data).

Comment: Hi @Andy, I am trying to have a clustered env setup through nifi. I feel this is some network issue in k8s. Because intermittently I get that exception.. I am suspecting, memory tuning parameters to give enough resources to the instances, that could work.